# Disable rotation on specific UIView iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, xamarin.ios, uiimageview, rotation

I have a view controller with this structure:

[image: layout structure]

I need to disable the rotation in `PVEdit Issue Photo Image View` and `PVEdit Issue Photo Hand Drawing View` when the device orientation is changed.

What I'm doing right now is trying to rotate the image inside `UIImageView` to make it looks like it's still in the same position.

What I'm trying to achieve is similar with SnapChat:

If I have landscape photo and my device orientation is landscape, then it will show the image with correct position.

[image: landscape image with landscape device orientation]

If I rotate my device to portrait, the image position is still the same. Only the edit buttons is rotated.

[image: landscape image with portrait device orientation]

How can I achieve something like this?